# Is there any way to have a catcode set only inside a macro?

Tags: catcodes

I was wondering if it's at all possible to change a catcode for use only inside a macro definition. In this case, I need to have one macro defined as `\example#1#2`, and another defined as `\example^#1#2`. The code below is working if `\test{\example^25}` is omitted. Thanks in advance (eplain answers only please).

```
\catcode`^=11

\def\example^#1#2{%
this is \#1: #1. this is \#2: #2}

\catcode`^=7

\def\test#1{%
\catcode`^=11
#1
\catcode`^=7}

\test{\example^25}

\bye
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No, it's not possible in that way (unless you allow `\scantokens` which is not in Knuth TeX).

Comment: I might be getting my jargon messed up. Maybe I meant etex and not eplain? scantokens is available to me, I just tried it with "\edef\test{\scantokens{test\noexpand}}" and \test expands to the text "test". I will look into scantokens now, thank you.

Comment: Are you bond to plain-TeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mostly depends on what `\example` is supposed to do. The standard way is to delay reading the argument: if you expect that `\test` can have both `\example` and `\example^` in its argument, define it as

```
\def\test{\begingroup\catcode`^=11 \dotest}
\def\dotest#1{#1\endgroup}
```

so the category code change happens *before* the argument is grabbed and catcodes frozen. Of course this has the limitation that `\test` cannot be itself used in the argument to another command.

A different strategy is to have just one `\example` macro:

```
\def\example{\futurelet\next\doexample}
\def\doexample{\ifx^\next\let\next\examplehat
  \else\let\next\examplenohat\fi\next}

\def\examplehat^#1#2{this is \#1: #1. this is \#2: #2}
\def\examplenohat#1#2{No hat (#1,#2)}
```

No category code change.

Full code:

```
\def\example{\futurelet\next\doexample}
\def\doexample{\ifx^\next\let\next\examplehat
  \else\let\next\examplenohat\fi\next}

\def\examplehat^#1#2{this is \#1: #1. this is \#2: #2}
\def\examplenohat#1#2{No hat (#1,#2)}

\example25

\example^25

\def\test#1{#1}

\test{\example25}

\test{\example^25}

\bye
```

[image]

With `\scantokens` we still have to delay grabbing the argument or it would already be tokenized at the category code change and control sequences formed.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`^=11
\gdef\example^#1#2{this is \#1: #1. this is \#2: #2}
\endgroup

\def\example#1#2{No hat (#1,#2)}

\def\test{\begingroup\catcode`^=11 \dotest}
\def\dotest#1{\scantokens{#1\noexpand}\endgroup}

X\test{\example25}X

X\test{\example^25}X

\bye
```

[image]