# Tikz's babel library not working under certain condition

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

The use of a functionality from the "quotes" library initially gave me an error.

I changed the babel's language from "brazilian" to "english", and it worked.

I went after a fix, and found out about the "babel" library; used it, and so it worked for the "normal" cases, but not inside the macro I defined.

Basically, that's how things are working:

1. english + (no quote package) = works for all cases
2. brazilian + (no quote package) = doesn't work
3. english + (quote package) = works for all cases
4. brazilian + (quote package) = works outside macros, but not inside these.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[brazil]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,angles,quotes}

\newcommand\fig[1]%
{\begin{tikzpicture}#1\end{tikzpicture}}%

\begin{document}

\fig{\coordinate (a) at (3.75,3.75);
  \coordinate (b) at (3.75,0.75);
  \coordinate (lo) at (0, 0.75);
  \draw[thick,blue] (0, 0.75) -- (3.75, 3.75);
  \pic [draw, -,thick,"$\theta$", angle radius=1cm, angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle = a--lo--b};}

\end{document}
```

It fails when "brazil" language is set, but it works when it's set to english.

Comment: Please post a full working MWE so we can replicate the issue. In the meantime also check `xparse` it comes with LaTeX2e and it is a better alternative than `xargs`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering and pointing it out. I just updated my post with the MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue also applies whit the option `german` for `babel`.

The reason is that the argument of the command `\fig` is not read with the correct catcodes. The `tikz` library `babel` resets some catcodes to their normal values at the beginning of every `tikzpicture` environment but the argument of `\fig` is read before this applies.

The solution is based on the answer from [Is there any way to have a catcode set only inside a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279261/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-catcode-set-only-inside-a-macro).

The command `\fig` starts with `\begingroup`. Then it sets the catcode of `"`. Only after this catcode is changed, the command `\figaux` is executed. At the end of `\figaux`, `\endgroup` is placed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[brazil]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,angles,quotes}
\newcommand{\fig}{\begingroup\catcode`"=12 \figaux}
\newcommand{\figaux}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}#1\end{tikzpicture}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\fig{\coordinate (a) at (3.75,3.75);
  \coordinate (b) at (3.75,0.75);
  \coordinate (lo) at (0, 0.75);
  \draw[thick,blue] (0, 0.75) -- (3.75, 3.75);
  \pic [draw, -,thick,"$\theta$", angle radius=1cm, angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle = a--lo--b};}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It fixed the problem.
I also appreciate your explanation.