\usetikzlibrary{babel} does not work
In this code:
I want to label an angle.
I made \loesung to make one document with \loesung to hide. Otherwise i allways need two documents and herw i can switch the toggle showcomment and everything is fine.
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%%%% NOT RELATED, BUT ADDED
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%%%% ADDED, SOLVES BABEL-QUOTES CLASH
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% ifthen
\newtoggle{showComments} %switch to show comments \mycomment und loesung

\newcommand{\loesung}[1]{
    \iftoggle{showComments}
    {\textbf{Lösung: }#1}
    {}
}

\toggletrue{showComments} % Zum Anzeigen von Kommentaren auf 'true' setzen, zum Ausblenden auf 'false' setzen
%\togglefalse{showComments}%zum Verbergen von \mycomment




\begin{document}
    \loesung{
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (HP) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
        % Winkel
        \draw pic [draw=orange, "$\beta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--HP};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
    
\end{document}

\usetikzlibrary{babel} does not work.
I do not understand why.
If i delete \loesung it works well, but i would like to have \loesung. \loesung works well with pgfplots and all other stuff since one year but not with \usetikzlibrary{babel}.
Thanks
Patrick

First of perhaps yuo should start by explaining what the expected outcome should be. Secondly if you remove \loesung{...} you'll see that it works just fine.

might be related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705767/36296

The tikz babel lib probably cannot do its thing when the entire thing is being used inside the argument of a macro, at that time it is too late.

How to change this. Why do all other libs i use work inside the makro and this library not. What can i change to change this?

Didn't you already ask this? Or something related?

OK, have to check. In the related code
~~\newcommand{\fig}{\begingroup\catcode`"=12 \figaux}
\newcommand{\figaux}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}#1\end{tikzpicture}\endgroup}~~~
\fig calls \figaux, but if i type \fig{blabla} how does figaux get this {blabla}.
Should it not be
~~~ \newcommand{\fig}[1]{\begingroup\catcode`"=12 \figaux{#1}}
\newcommand{\figaux}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}#1\end{tikzpicture}\endgroup}~~~?
New Question because people told me to do so.
Thanks
PS. How can i edit code in a comment? As you see i coud not.

Seems you've not tested it :(. However, \fig does not need to read the argument, because it ends with \fixaux and \fixaux reads the argument. This is similar to \newcommnd*{\textfoo}{\textbf}. And \fig must not the read the argument, because it would read it with unchanged catcodes. So the " inside the argument would still be a babel shortcut. \catcode does not change the catcode of already build tokens. The trick is to change the \catcode before reading the argument.

Do you actually need babel shorthands? With utf8 now being the default, you can just type üöä etc. directly.

Tried
\newcommand{\loesung}{
 \iftoggle{showComments}
 {\begingroup\catcode`"=12 \loesungaux}
 {}
}
\newcommand{\loesungaux}[1]{
  {\textbf{Lösung: }#1}
 }
''''
But then in the document is only "Lösung", no pgfplot. 
Same with

\usepackage[ngerman, shorthands=off]{babel}


Sorry, i do not know if i need those babel shorthands. I really try to understand everything but there is no person i can ask and the manuals are written for people who do not need manuals.

@Patrick In this case you probably don't need them. Switch them off as suggested by @ Rmano and avoid all the potential problems they cause.

Sorry, i was looking for the angle as in the orignal tikzpicture.
What would yo prefer, the solution with
```\loesungaux````` or the solution with  \usepackage[ngerman, shorthands=off]{babel}
I am afraid the later one causes more problems in other cases.
Thanks Patrick

Something must still be wrong. How should i post the corrected code? I do not want to make something wrong again with comment or answer.
But no time now, maybe sunday.
Greetings
Patrick

If you have a new question related to an existing question or answer → I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?. The suggestions there are mainly for those who posted a question as an answer, but several are also valid before doing it wrong, i.e. ask a new question with reference and explain why the shown answers to the original question do not help. To illustrate this a real MWE, that shows what you've tried, is always useful.

BTW: Code in comments is a mess. And questioners should never hide relevant information in comments. They should always add them to the question or — if this crucial would change an already answered question — ask a new follow-up question with the new information as explained above.
